# webkitMediaStream Object Type lost while using sendMessage in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, casting, sendmessage

So I'm trying to capture web audio from a tab and pass it into another script that works with DOM elements on the page.

**EXTENSION SCRIPT**

In the `background.js`, I use the following script:

```
    chrome.tabCapture.capture(constraints, function(stream) {
        console.log("\ngot stream");
        console.log(stream);

        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabID, {
            "message": "stream",
            "stream": stream
        });
    });
```

The Developer Toolkit shows me that the created object is indeed a MediaStream object. (Which I want and appears to be working fine).

**EXTENSION CONSOLE:**

`MediaStream {onremovetrack: null, onaddtrack: null, onended: null, ended: false, id: "c0jm4lYJus3XCwQgesUGT9lpyPQiWlGKHb7q"…}`

**CONTENT SCRIPT**

I use a content script (injected), on the page itself to then pull the JSON serialized object back out:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.message === "stream") {
    var thisStream = request.stream;
    console.log(thisStream);
    if (!thisStream) {
      console.log("stream is null");
      return;
    }    
    loadStream(thisStream);
  }
  else if (request.message === "statusChanged") {
    console.log("statusChanged");
  }
});
```

**PAGE CONSOLE**

Unfortunately, because of JSON serialization, the object type is lost:

`Object {onremovetrack: null, onaddtrack: null, onended: null, ended: false, id: "c0jm4lYJus3XCwQgesUGT9lpyPQiWlGKHb7q"…}`

I need the object recast as a MediaStream object and have tried the following things which all failed:

**Attempt 1: FAILED**

```
var stream = new webkitMediaStream;
function loadStream(thisStream) {
    stream = thisStream;
}
```

**Attempt 2: FAILED**

```
var stream;
function loadStream(thisStream) {
    stream = new webkitMediaStream(thisStream);
}
```

**Attempt 3: FAILED**

```
var stream;
function loadStream(thisStream) {
    stream = Object.create(webkitMediaStream, thisStream);
}
```

**NOTE:**
The constructor for the `MediaStream` object ***IS*** `webkitMediaStream`.

I need either a better method for passing the object from the extension script (the only place the `chrome.tab.capture()` method works from) to the content script (the only place that has access to and can modify the DOM elements of the page),

**OR**

I need a way of recasting the JSON serialized object back into a fully functional `MediaStream` object.

Thanks in advance!

JRad the Bad

Answer (score 7):

Extension messages are always JSON-serialized, so it's indeed obvious that you cannot send a `MediaStream` from the background page to the web page. The question is, do you really need to send the `MediaStream` from the background to the content script?

- If you only need to, e.g. display the video, then you can use [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to get a `blob:`-URL for the stream and assign it to `video.src` to see a video. The URL created by `URL.createObjectURL` can only be used by a page at the same origin, so you need to create the `<video>` tag in a `chrome-extension://` page; either in a tab, or in a frame. If you want to do this in a frame, make sure that the page is listed in [`web_accessible_resources`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).

If you DO *really* need a `MediaStream` object of the tab in the tab, then [`RTCPeerConnection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection) can be used to send the stream. This WebRTC API is normally used to exchange media streams between peers in a network, but it can also be used to send streams from one page to another page in another tab or browser.

Here's a full example. Visit any web page, and click on the extension button. Then the extension will insert a video in the page showing the current tab.

background.js

```js
function sendStreamToTab(tabId, stream) {
    var pc = new webkitRTCPeerConnection({iceServers:[]});
    pc.addStream(stream);
    pc.createOffer(function(offer) {
        pc.setLocalDescription(offer, function() {
            // Use chrome.tabs.connect instead of sendMessage
            // to make sure that the lifetime of the stream
            // is tied to the lifetime of the consumer (tab).
            var port = chrome.tabs.connect(tabId, {name: 'tabCaptureSDP'});
            port.onDisconnect.addListener(function() {
                stopStream(stream);
            });
            port.onMessage.addListener(function(sdp) {
                pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(sdp));
            });
            port.postMessage(pc.localDescription);
        });
    });
}

function stopStream(stream) {
    var tracks = this.getTracks();
    for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; ++i) {
        tracks[i].stop();
    }
}

function captureTab(tabId) {
    // Note: this method must be invoked by the user as defined
    // in https://crbug.com/489258, e.g. chrome.browserAction.onClicked.
    chrome.tabCapture.capture({
        audio: true,
        video: true,
        audioConstraints: {
            mandatory: {
                chromeMediaSource: 'tab',
            },
        },
        videoConstraints: {
            mandatory: {
                chromeMediaSource: 'tab',
            },
        },
    }, function(stream) {
        if (!stream) {
            alert('Stream creation failed: ' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        }
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: 'contentscript.js'}, function() {
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                stopStream(stream);
                alert('Script injection failed:' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
            } else {
                sendStreamToTab(tabId, stream);
            }
        });
    });
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    captureTab(tab.id);
});
```

contentscript.js

```js
function onReceiveStream(stream) {
    // Just to show that we can receive streams:
    var video = document.createElement('video');
    video.style.border = '1px solid black';
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    document.body.insertBefore(video, document.body.firstChild);
}

function onReceiveOfferSDP(sdp, sendResponse) {
    var pc = new webkitRTCPeerConnection({iceServers:[]});
    pc.onaddstream = function(event) {
        onReceiveStream(event.stream);
    };
    pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(sdp), function() {
        pc.createAnswer(function(answer) {
            pc.setLocalDescription(answer);
            sendResponse(pc.localDescription);
        });
    });
}

// Run once to prevent the message from being handled twice when
// executeScript is called multiple times.
if (!window.hasRun) {
    window.hasRun = 1;
    chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
        if (port.name === 'tabCaptureSDP') {
            port.onMessage.addListener(function(remoteDescription) {
                onReceiveOfferSDP(remoteDescription, function(sdp) {
                    port.postMessage(sdp);
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

manifest.json

```js
{
    "name": "tabCapture to tab",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Capture tab"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabCapture"
    ]
}
```